# C++ Nested Primitive Type Templates

Tags: templates, c++11

I've been working on a pixel format and canvas system using templates with primitive type arguments, that is:

```
enum class PIXEL_FORMAT : char {
    PALETTE,
    RGB,
    RGBA
};

template<unsigned int bit_depth, PIXEL_FORMAT fmt> struct Pixel {};

//specializations for 8-bit, 16-bit, etc. RGB/RGBA formats
```

These all work perfectly fine, but when I attempted to create a Layer struct:

```
template< template<unsigned int depth, PIXEL_FORMAT fmt> class PixelType > struct Layer {
using pixel = PixelType<depth, fmt>;
pixel** pixels;
```

The errors I got were:

```
F:\Personal Projects (Java or Other)\C_C++\Independent\GUI Apps\FreeArt\Canvas.h|7|error: 'depth' was not declared in this scope
F:\Personal Projects (Java or Other)\C_C++\Independent\GUI Apps\FreeArt\Canvas.h|7|error: 'fmt' was not declared in this scope
F:\Personal Projects (Java or Other)\C_C++\Independent\GUI Apps\FreeArt\Canvas.h|7|error: template argument 1 is invalid
F:\Personal Projects (Java or Other)\C_C++\Independent\GUI Apps\FreeArt\Canvas.h|7|error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

So obviously I'm not understanding the way nested templates using primitive types as parameters work. I've looked for similar issues, but can't seem to find anything on using primitive types instead of regular template arguments (`typename T`, etc).

I'm hoping this can be used for other types with templates using primitive type arguments, for example a possible

```
template<template<unsigned int bit_depth, double samp_per_sec> class Sound> struct SoundEffect {};
```

Comment: People will understand better what you're asking for if you end with a direct question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a single pixel type in a layer, then you need this:

```
template < typename PixelType > struct Layer {
   ...
};

using RGBA8Layer = Layer < Pixel<8, RGBA> >;
```

If you need to access `bit_depth` and `format` from within `Layer`, define static const members in either `Pixel` or in a separate "traits" template.

The construct you are trying to use is called "template template parameter". They are needed when you have potentially many templates with the same signature:

```
template <unsigned int bit_depth, PIXEL_FORMAT fmt> struct Pixel {};
template <unsigned int bit_depth, PIXEL_FORMAT fmt> struct FancyPixel {};
template <unsigned int bit_depth, PIXEL_FORMAT fmt> struct FastPixel {};
template <unsigned int bit_depth, PIXEL_FORMAT fmt> struct PackedPixel {};
```

and you wanted to use any of them with `Layer`, *and* you wanted to select depth and format *from inside the layer*, then you would use this:

```
template< template<unsigned int, PIXEL_FORMAT> class PixelType > 
struct Layer {
    using MyNormalPixel = PixelType<8, RGB>;
    using MyHighDefinitionPixel = PixelType<16, RGBA>;
};

using FancyLayer = Layer<FancyPixel>;
using PackedLayer = Layer<PackedPixel>;
```

Notice how parameter names in `PixelType` are omitted — they cannot be used in the code at all. The only thing they are useful for is documentation. The situation is analogous to that of function arguments:

```
// signature off the top of my head
double integrate (double func(double), 
                  double from, double to, double epsilon, double step);
```

Indeed, templates are in essence functions in the types domain and "template template parameters" are analogous to "function function parameters" like `func` above.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back, my laptop's battery died. So I'm essentially going to need to `typedef` each type of Pixel I might use? Would I be able to use PixelType as a sort of interface, allowing me to make a `PixelType**` for the array creation/resize? Other than that I think I have a better understanding now, thanks.

Comment: You don't *need* to typedef each pixel type, this is just an illustration. But you may want to, if it's easier to read this way. Inside the Layer template PixelType is just a type and you certainly can make `PixelType**`, but better use a `vector<vector<PixelType>>`.